# Why doesn't polling require a context switch?

Tags: interrupts, microprocessor

When we have a microproccessor and we must service the peripherals, the theory suggests that we can use either interrupts (context switch required) or polling (no context switch required.) On the first instance, what we do when we receive the interrupt is finish our current command and then:

1. Switch context (program counter, flags, registers etc.)
2. Call the interrupt service routine (ISR)
3. Restore the previous context
4. Return to our program's next command

If instead of interrupts we use polling, what we do is essentially execute our program normally and scan periodically for peripherals that may need service. If we detect a peripheral that needs service wouldn't we have to switch context in order to execute the ISR? What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't know what you're missing, honestly. You just don't have to do anything of 1.-4..

Comment: If you are polling peripherals, you don't use interrupts.  When you find a peripheral that needs service, your main program jumps to a subroutine that services the peripheral, then returns to continue the main program.  With polling, you (or your main program) are in control of what happens when.  With interrupts, the peripherals interrupt the main program whenever they want.

Comment: So with polling do I have to add the "handling code" inside my main program?

Comment: @user1198483 Yes, or a subroutine of it.

Comment: This is what I have understood: with interrupts I don't know when I will receive one and that's why I need the context switch so I can "protect" the content or my registers etc at that time. But with polling since I decide exactly when I am going to do the handling (assuming that a peripheral needs it at that time)  I know exactly wich registers are free and which aren't, so I write my handling code accordingly. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but your polling frequency must be above the highest peripheral event frequency.

Comment: Quick answer:  Polling occurs in what some of us call *"the main event loop"*, which is the top-level of the program running in the embedded processor.  You poll each peripheral and ask it if it needs any attention.  If it says it does, attend to it.  If it does not, poll the next peripheral device in the list.

Comment: Ok I get it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In polling, there are no interrupts.  The routine that would have been the ISR can be replaced with a simple function call, which requires no context switch.

The software can be a single loop.  It checks each of the periplerals in turn.  If one requires some action, it calls the required function to perform the action.  Then it moves on to the next peripheral.

Comment: Now it makes sense, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote more about how to handle things using interrupts. But then I re-read your question:

> But if instead of interrupts we use polling what we do is essentially
> execute our program normally and scan periodically for peripherals
> that may need service. So if we detect a peripheral that needs service
> wouldn't we have to switch context in order to execute the ISR? So
> what am I missing here?

So no discussion of handling interrupts on the current process thread stack or anything else like that. Instead, I'm just going to provide a reason why *not* to use polling taken from a real-life example.

The device was (still is) a measurement instrument. And it has a number of important tasks, including of course taking measurements and presenting them via analog outputs and displaying the information. The usual stuff. But it also has a very limited-tech keypad on the front panel that includes some special keys that are like `shift` and `ctrl` in order to add functionality without having to completely redo the front panel every time. They have to be examined often enough that a user doesn't notice and this keyboard was initially polled.

Polling calls used to monitor the keypad were salted throughout the code. In fact, because the measurement calculations involved long, drawn-out calculations and table lookups these polling calls also had to be salted throughout the middle of these calculations or else the user would very much notice the lack of response. (The complaints did, of course, pour in.)

The keyboard state has to include prior state of earlier keys, as well, as key combinations were supported. Worse, the keyboard scanning code had to branch back to appropriate places within its code body, based upon what prior keys had been recognized. Only that way would it know how to provide errors or actions that were context sensitive. So the polling code, when called, had a lot more code designed only for the purpose to re-position itself back to where it should have been, the last time when it processed the last scanned key and was waiting for more.

Eventually, this all became completely unmaintainable code. Users would still periodically find certain activities that made the keyboard responsiveness unacceptable. The fix was always to add more salted code and issue software updates.

You get the idea. Certainly, the developer of this code got the idea because one of several differents tasks I was given as a consultant was to fix the resulting rats' nest of code.

I do polling all the time for simple tests and validation purposes. But as a guide for commercial application code, polling in the main-line code is something I generally avoid.

Comment: Seems like "responsiveness" of servicing the peripherals is a strong advantage of interrupts over polling, something that isn't mentioned often in literature.